# Build phase fails with undefined reference to `evhttp_uridecode`

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, ubuntu, compiling

I try to build Bitcoin Core on my Ubuntu 23.10 machine using the ["Build Unix" documentation page](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md) but it fails with undefined reference to `evhttp_uridecode`.

Here are the details:

I started by cloning the repo locally and using the v26.0 tag:

```
git clone git@github.com:bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin
git checkout v26.0
```

Then installed the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install -y build-essential libtool autotools-dev automake pkg-config bsdmainutils python3
sudo apt install -y libevent-dev libboost-dev
sudo apt install -y libzmq3-dev systemtap-sdt-dev
```

I'm not interested in building the wallet, but just the P2P protocol, so I skipped the other installs.

Then starts the build phase:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --disable-bench --disable-fuzz-binary --enable-debug --without-gui \
            --enable-suppress-external-warnings --disable-wallet
make -j 4
```

This last `make` commands returns an error after some time:

```
...
  CXXLD    libbitcoinconsensus.la
  AR       libbitcoin_util.a
  CXXLD    bitcoin-cli
  CXXLD    bitcoin-tx
  CXXLD    bitcoin-util
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_common.a(libbitcoin_common_a-url.o): in function `urlDecode(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/hassen/Workspace/OpenSource/bitcoin/src/common/url.cpp:15:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `evhttp_uridecode'
/usr/bin/ld: libbitcoin_common.a(libbitcoin_common_a-url.o): in function `urlDecode(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/hassen/Workspace/OpenSource/bitcoin/src/common/url.cpp:15:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `evhttp_uridecode'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:7407: bitcoin-util] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:7403: bitcoin-tx] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/hassen/Workspace/OpenSource/bitcoin/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:20138: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hassen/Workspace/OpenSource/bitcoin/src'
make: *** [Makefile:814: all-recursive] Error 1
```

It looks like the issue is that `evhttp_uridecode` is not found. However I'm pretty sure I installed all the necessary packages.

If this can help, running `uname -a` on my machine returns:

```
Linux XPS-machine 6.5.0-14-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 14 14:59:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/29654.

Answer (score 0):

This bug only occurs when linking the `bitcoin-util` and `bitcoin-wallet` tools. The simplest workaround would be to disable those by adding `--disable-util-util --disable-util-wallet` to your `configure` command line.

If you want to build them anyway, this patch should work:

```
--- a/src/Makefile.am
+++ b/src/Makefile.am
@@ -715,11 +715,6 @@ libbitcoin_common_a_SOURCES = \
   script/solver.cpp \
   warnings.cpp \
   $(BITCOIN_CORE_H)
-
-if USE_LIBEVENT
-libbitcoin_common_a_CPPFLAGS += $(EVENT_CFLAGS)
-libbitcoin_common_a_SOURCES += common/url.cpp
-endif
 #
 
 # util #
@@ -765,6 +760,11 @@ libbitcoin_util_a_SOURCES = \
   util/time.cpp \
   util/tokenpipe.cpp \
   $(BITCOIN_CORE_H)
+
+if USE_LIBEVENT
+libbitcoin_util_a_CPPFLAGS += $(EVENT_CFLAGS)
+libbitcoin_util_a_SOURCES += common/url.cpp
+endif
 #
 
 # cli #
```